# R function to find Fibonacci numbers

Tags: r, fibonacci

New to R, so apologies for any mistakes. I am making a R function to find 20 Fibonacci numbers starting from 1. I made this function, however the function outputs Fibonacci numbers like this:

```
# Output
1  1  2  3  5  8  13   21   34   55   89  144  233  377  610  987 1597 2584 4181 6765
```

I want this:

```
1  2  3  5  8  13   21   34   55   89  144  233  377  610  987 1597 2584 4181 6765 10946
```

What troubles me is I don't want 2 'ones' at start. Only one "1" at start is required. Also, having trouble in function calling. Here is my code:

```
Ms <- function(moving_sum) {
  Fib <- numeric(20)
  Fib[1]  <- Fib[2] <- 1
  for (i in 3:20) Fib[i] <- Fib[i - 2] + Fib[i - 1] 
  return(Fib)
}

Ms(0)
```

Thanks.

## --- Update ---

How to find the total count of even numbers? And the total sum of those even numbers?

Comment: How about just  `return(Fib[-1])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

incorporate the following changes

```
Ms <- function(moving_sum) {
  Fib <- numeric(moving_sum + 1) # Use the parameter moving_sum
  Fib[1]  <- Fib[2] <- 1
  for (i in seq(3, moving_sum + 1)) Fib[i] <- Fib[i - 2] + Fib[i - 1] 
  return(Fib[-1]) # Remove the first number
}

Ms(20)
 [1]     1     2     3     5     8    13    21    34    55    89   144   233   377
[14]   610   987  1597  2584  4181  6765 10946
```

Comment: I just made a slight change to my question. Can you please check it?

Comment: @Zaif what do you mean? What even numbers?

Comment: I mean how to calculate how many even numbers are there in these Fibonacci numbers? And what is the total sum of those even numbers?

Comment: @Zaif you can do that as follows: `fibs <- Ms(20); even_fibs <- fibs[!fibs%%2]; length(even_fibs); sum(even_fibs);`

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
Ms <- function() {
  Fib <- numeric(20)
  Fib[1:2] <- 1:2
  for (i in 3:20) Fib[i] <- Fib[i - 2] + Fib[i - 1]
  evenFibs <- Fib[Fib %% 2 == 0]
  list(
    Fibs = Fib,
    nrOfFibs = length(evenFibs),
    sumEvenFibs = sum(evenFibs)
  )
}
```

and you will get

```
> Ms()
$Fibs
 [1]     1     2     3     5     8    13    21    34    55    89   144   233
[13]   377   610   987  1597  2584  4181  6765 10946

$nrOfFibs
[1] 7

$sumEvenFibs
[1] 14328
```